# What is wrong in this code, why does it print only the first code block

Tags: javascript

When const is false why does it still print the first code block, apologies.

```
const fireIsHot= "true";
 if (fireIsHot) {
     console.log("Fire is hot!");
} else {
     console.log("Fire is not hot!");
}
```

Comment: `"true"` is a string. `true` is a boolean value. 2 very different things

Comment: The string `"false"` is truthy. The boolean `false` is not.

Comment: Sike, sorry all, thanks a lot,.only strings should be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: @MrPain it’s not that only strings should be in quotation marks, it’s that strings _are_ values in quotation marks.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I understand you though a part of me feels like I don't,  sorry for stressing y'all.

Comment: Any value in a quote ( "Pain" )is a string, in this case - Pain is a string .